# Ruby Gem: Install configuration files to the user-home directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems, config

I have to make a REST-Client in Ruby.

The client must be runnable from the command-line like a binary and also it must be "requirable" in a ruby script and provide different functions.

My gemspec does exactly what it should.

But i have no idea how to install a configuration file (YAML) in the user-home folder?
The config file should be in the user directory to provide easy access for the user.

- Is this even possible?
- Should i check on the first run if there is a config file and create it?
- Can i execute an own installation routine while installing a gem?

I did exactly the same thing in Python and it worked fine, so the Ruby client should behave similar.

Comment: Install to home directory on first run. That's the way to do it.

Comment: But the config parameters are not known. The User has to modify the configuration to his needs. -> it will get very dirty

Comment: How about asking the user the relevant config questions on the first run? I think you could also do global configuration during installation using the RubyGems `extconf.rb` mechanism that is usually reserved for building platform binaries.

Answer (score 0):

For such decisions, I wrote gem [persey](https://github.com/zzet/persey). If you look at the [description](https://github.com/zzet/persey#definition) of the use of this gem, you can see that it provides what you expect:

```
# Rails.root are not initialized here
app_path = File.expand_path('../../', __FILE__)

# ...

# config with secret keys
# you don't want store this config in repository and copy to secret folder on host machine
my_secret_key_config = '/home/user/secret/keys.yml'

# ...

# Persey.init ENV["environment"] do # set current environment
Persey.init Rails.env do # set current environment

  source :yaml, my_secret_key_config, :secret   # no comments. It's secret!

  env :production do
    # ...
  end

  env :development, :parent => :production do
    # ...
  end
end
```